# Create delegate for jQuery extension method

Tags: jquery, design-patterns, delegates

Assume I have jQuery extension method defined as:

```
$.fn.myMethod = function(text)
{
     $(this).text(text); ///
}
```

I also might have similar method:

```
$.fn.myMethod2 = function(text)
{
    $(this).text(text + " superduper");
}
```

Now assume I have some configuration class that looks like this:

```
var myConfig =
{
    myMethod:  /// this should be delegate to one of the above
}
```

What I aim for is that somewhere in my code, I might type something like:

```
$("selector").myConfig.myMethod("Insert this");
```

Basically myConfig.myMethod is delegate to either myMethod or myMethod2. I do this regularly with my own functions, but I'm not sure on how to implement his properly with jQuery methods and I'm more interested in learning the proper way rather than experimenting and potentially creating something wrong.